# PHPMailer doesn't send Mails with IsHTML(true) or any HTML Code

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I'm currently trying to get PHPMailer to send an E-Mail with a verification Link.
To get this done I need to use the html A Tag so I set IsHTML true but somehow the Mails won't go out then anymore.

Here's my current code.

```
    //Send Welcome E-Mail
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.yaay.de";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = "465";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Username = "admin@whatever.net";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "pass"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "admin@whatever.net";
$mail->FromName = "Whatever";
$mail->AddAddress($receiver, $receivername);                  // name is optional

$mail->Subject = "Welcome, $receivername!";
$mail->Body    = "To activate your Account, please visit the following link: <a href = '?test'>test</a>";
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Send();

if(!$mail->Send())
{
    die($mail->ErrorInfo);
}
```

No errror is displayed, I have no idea how to find out where the problem is. :(
I just know that any html code or IsHTML(true) is enough to kill the E-Mail sending process. :/

Comment: why you are doing `$mail->Send()` twice?

Comment: Didn't realize it, but shouldn't be the problem tho. 
When I delete the $mail->Send(); line it still won't get send..

Comment: Are you getting any error in `$mail->ErrorInfo`?

Comment: Nope, thats the problem.
Regarding to the Code $mail-Send(); isn't throwing any errors, it works "just fine"... hahaha :(

Comment: if `$mail->Send()` is returning `TRUE` then just look into your span or junk folder

Comment: I got it working, I guess the problem was partly fault of my e-mail provider, the spam got swallowed and it landed in spam. :/
Now I just gotta find out how to get my E-Mail out of the Spam Folder. :)